# How do I refer to ASP.NET identity Usermanager inside of a static class?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I want to create a new user during the seed method of the program but how do I call CreateAsync??

```
 public class DbInitializer
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public DbInitializer(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public static void Initialize(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        OneDbContext context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<OneDbContext>();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        //If there are no users, create a test user
        if (!context.Users.Any())
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "test", Email = "test@test.com" };
            var result =  _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "test");
        }
```

error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DbInitializer._userManager'

Comment: You can get a `UserManager` from DI the same way you're getting an instance of your DbContext e.g. `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();`.